# Inverse Laplace transform of hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

can anyone tell me how can I seek the inverse Laplace transform of equation $F(s)=\frac{p}{s}-\frac{p}{s}\frac{sinh(a\sqrt{s})}{sinh(b\sqrt{s})}$, where $p$, $a$, and $b$ are positive constants independent on $s$.

I found in a hand book that $L^{-1}\{\frac{1}{s-iw}\frac{sinh(a\sqrt{s})}{sinh(b\sqrt{s})}\} = \frac{sinh(a\sqrt{wi})}{sinh(b\sqrt{wi})}e^{iwt} + 2\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n (-1)^n sin(n\pi a/b)}{n^2 \pi^2 + iwb^2}e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t/b}$, but I don't know how to handle the first term since $w=0$.

Many thanks to your help. A detailed explanation will be highly appreciated, since I'm new in Laplace transform and I really don't have much knowledge in complex analysis.

Comment: $$\frac{\sinh(a\sqrt{wi})}{\sinh(b\sqrt{wi})}e^{iwt}\to\frac{a\sqrt{wi}}{b\sqrt{wi}}=\frac ab\,\, \text{at}\,\, |w|\to0$$

Comment: You can find similar Laplace inversions at [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737390/inverse-laplace-transform-of-frac-sqrt2s-sinh-sqrt2s-and-frac1-c/4426693#4426693) [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965257/inverse-laplace-of-frac-sinhx-sqrtss2-sinh-sqrts) [link3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224588/inverse-laplace-transform-of-frac%CF%80-cosh-sqrt-s2-s3-2-sinh-sqrt-s?rq=1).